# How to find maximum number of communities available in org

Tags: community

Is there any way to know maximum number of published communities available for an organisation?

I know we can go **customize -> manage communities** and see how many communities are available.

But this is possible only if you enable communities. Before enabling is there a way of finding this out??

Comment: Did you get the answer for your question? I also need the same information.

Answer (score 1):

There's no programmatic way to determine this value. You can check your current status by logging in and checking it manually. You can't exceed the limit, so you can check to see if you get an error message when trying to publish a new community.

Comment: well ,it is not enabled at the moment .So publishing and all is not possible.Once it is enabled,its easy to detect .my usecase is to know how many are possible without enabling communities